# How to define a separate set of styles for each platform/OS in Avalonia?

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui

Is there a way to apply different styles depending on the operation system? How does one define separate themes for Windows, macOS and Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently only one "default" theme, platform-specific themes are planned, but not yet implemented.

If you want per-platform themes/styles, you need to add them to your `Application.Styles` manually inside `Application.Initialize` using `StyleInclude` class (See `App.xaml` from application template). For platform detection you can use `AvaloniaLocator.Current.GetService<IRuntimePlatform>().GetRuntimeInfo().OperatingSystem`.

Comment: This solution doesn't apply to Avalonia 11+.